# Form data not being submitted on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to make an ajax call every time user change its profile picture. I can make ajax call successfully but problem is that nothing sent to the server.

```
<form action="#" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="avatar-upload-form">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block">
              Upload new picture <input type="file" style="display: none;" name="profile_image" id="profile_image">
       </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$('#profile_image').on('change', function() {
    var formData = new FormData("#avatar-upload-form");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/users/upload/avatar',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache:false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }, 
        error: function(error) {
           console.log(error);
        }
     })
});
```

[image]

**PHP Code**

```
Route::post('/users/upload/avatar', function() {
   dd(Request::file('profile_image')); // return empty array
});
```

Comment: it would be better if you post php code here

Comment: The FormData object still has limited support. I would recommend doing something like ``var formData = $('#formid').serialize()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this problem on my own. I just need to use standard javascript form object like so:
`document.getElementById('form_id')[0]`